# htaccess relative redirect to parent directory + hash

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I redirect this using the same rule:
http://dev.loc/pets/work/user/some.user
http://dev.loc/pets/work/#user=some.user

https://example.com/user/some.user
https://example.com/#user=some.user

Probably with some RewriteBase?

Comment: Check out: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: This handles hashes but not relative paths (I added another example).   `/bigpage.html#$1` redirects to the root aka `http://dev.loc/bigpage.html#user=some.user` and  `bigpage.html#$1` uses real path `http://dev.loc/Users/mu3/dbx/Dev/Web/pets/work/bigpage.html#user=some.user`

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: `~/dbx/Dev/Web/pets/work/` ; `http://dev.loc` point to `~/dbx/Dev/Web/`

Comment: Setting the RewriteBase to that directory, e.g. `/work/`, will send you to `bigpage.html` in that directory.  `RewriteBase /work/`
`RewriteRule "^user/(.+)" "bigpage.html#user=$1" [NE,R]`

Answer (score 1):

To redirect

- /pets/work/user/some.user

to

- /pets/work/#user=some.user

You can use something like the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pets/work/user/(.+)$ /pepts/work/#user=$1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: yeah but a path has to be dynamic/relative because of different domains